# Can't get max width to work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get 6 boxes to fit on a single line and change with screen resolution. I don't want them moving into 2 lines. I've tried combination after combination of code I could. My ideal width and height is 250px with the padding/margin between them equal. I'm not sure what else to do...

[Here's the jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/1vyoo6u2/)

```css
#boxes {} #boxes div {} #calculator {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: medium;
  margin: auto;
}
#lore {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: medium;
  margin: auto;
}
#artwork {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: medium;
  margin: auto;
}
#news {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: medium;
  margin: auto;
}
#tips {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: medium;
  margin: auto;
}
#easter_eggs {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: medium;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="boxes">
    <div id="calculator">
      <p>TEST</p>
    </div>

    <div id="lore">
      <p>TEST</p>
    </div>

    <div id="artwork">
      <p>TEST</p>
    </div>

    <div id="news">
      <p>TEST</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tips">
      <p>TEST</p>
    </div>

    <div id="easter_eggs">
      <p>TEST</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you have 6 boxes of 250px (plus extra padding/border) you need a minimum of 1500px width. what do you want to happen on smaller screens?

Comment: I would recommend to use `class` for mutiple use :D

Comment: Change your widths to be a percentage (ie. 1/6 of total, minus a bit for borders etc). 14% seems reasonably close.  Also what l2aelba said about classes

Comment: @JRQ is it better to use classes than id? or am I using id wrong?

Comment: Since all your elements have the same style properties, it's better to not repeat yourself. So, yes, in this case class is better than id.

Comment: @ColtonHorvath, Yep, you can still using IDs like this but make some class for styling

Comment: Expanding on @Dekel's comment: 250px × 6 = 1500px total width you'd need to show all six in a row, so you need to decide: do you want **1).** To *always* have 6 in a row, even if this means they end up less than 250px wide, or ** 2).** Have more than one row when the screen size is less than 1500px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this is what you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/1vyoo6u2/1/

```
#boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
#boxes div{
    width:14vmax;
    height:14vmax;
    max-height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height:250px;
    border:solid black;
    border-width:medium;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I changed your style and used flexbox to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use max width for what you want to achieve, change your stylesheet to the following:

```css
#boxes {
  text-align:center;
}
#boxes div { display:inline-block;
width:calc(16.66% - 10px);
}

#calculator {
 display:inline-block;
 height:100%;
 max-height:250px;
 border:solid black;
 border-width:medium;
 margin:auto;
}

#lore {
 display:inline-block;
 height:100%;
 max-height:250px;
 border:solid black;
 border-width:medium;
 margin:auto;
}

#artwork {
 display:inline-block;
 height:100%;
 max-height:250px;
 border:solid black;
 border-width:medium;
 margin:auto;
}

#news {
 display:inline-block;
 height:100%;
 max-height:250px;
 border:solid black;
 border-width:medium;
 margin:auto;
}

#tips {
 display:inline-block;
 height:100%;
 max-height:250px;
 border:solid black;
 border-width:medium;
 margin:auto;
}

#easter_eggs {
 display:inline-block;
 height:100%;
 max-height:250px;
 border:solid black;
 border-width:medium;
 margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="calculator">
    <p>TEST</p>
  </div>

  <div id="lore">
    <p>TEST</p>
  </div>

  <div id="artwork">
    <p>TEST</p>
  </div>

  <div id="news">
    <p>TEST</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tips">
    <p>TEST</p>
  </div>

  <div id="easter_eggs">
    <p>TEST</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!

Comment: I'd swap out `calc` in favour of simply using `width: 16.6%;` and `box-sizing:padding-box;`. Visually you get the same effect, but with higher browser support (83% vs 98% support).

Comment: great comment, thanks for that.